# React Dropdown menu not showing the selected element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm a beginner with React. In the code below I'm basically reading data from a db using flask api and returning data based on the option selected from a Dynamic dropdown list which also picks options to display from another flask api.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';

class ListUser extends Component{


  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state={
        userList:[],
        selected_eml:[],
        selected_email:'',
        user_list:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){

        axios.get('/getuserList',{crossDomain: true})
          .then(response => {
              if (response.status === 200 && response != null){
                console.log("user list",response.data)
                  this.setState({ userList : response.data,selected_eml:response.data});
                }
            })
  }        

  selectedUserHandler(event){
    this.setState({selected_eml: event.label})
    let email = event.value
    axios.get('/getUserlisting/'+email).then(response=>{
      if (response.status === 200 && response != null){
        this.setState({ user_list : response.data });
        console.log(response.data)
      } else {console.log("error")}
    })
   } 

componentDidUpdate(){
    let email = this.state.selected_eml
    axios.get('/getUserlisting/'+email).then(response=>{
      if (response.status === 200 && response != null){
        if(JSON.stringify(this.state.user_list) != JSON.stringify(response.data)){
        this.setState({ user_list : response.data, selected_email:response.data });
        console.log(response.data)
      }
      } else {console.log("error")}
    }) 
  }    

  render(){
    var filter_user_list=[]

    for (var key in this.state.selected_eml) {
            console.log(this.state.selected_eml[key]['value'])
            filter_user_list.push(this.state.selected_eml[key]['value'])
          }
          console.log(filter_user_list)

    return(
    <div>
      <div className="App">
        <table><tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th ><label> Email </label></th>
                     <td style= {{ width:"300px"}}>
                      <Select
                        placeholder= "Select User Email"
                        options={this.state.userList} value={this.state.selected_eml}
                        onChange={this.selectedUserHandler.bind(this)}
                       />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
          <h4 align="center">User List</h4>
          <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 10, border : 1 }} >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>User ID</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>P ID</th>
                <th>P Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody align="center">
             { this.state.user_list.map((mp, index)=><tr>
                <td> {mp.user_id} </td>
                <td> {mp.email} </td>
                <td> {mp.id} </td>
                <td> {mp.name} </td>
              </tr>) }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        </div>
      )

    }
}    

export default ListUser;
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I select an option from the dropdown, it returns data fine but doesn't show the option selected in the dropdown placeholder bar. I've tried passing `selected_eml` with `bind(this)` in `selectedUserHandler` function being passed in `onChange` and `getOption` methods but with no luck.

Also, if there is any way to make the code more efficient and improve quality, inputs are most welcome.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your parentheses `(mp, index)=><tr>` before `<tr>` there has to be a `(`. And another closing one here `</tr>)) }`.

Comment: The code was running fine, no errors returned or anything but I'll try what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selected value for the Select needs to have this object format of `{value: sth, label: sth}` in order to be displayed in the select container. And since you've assigned the `event.label` to the selected_eml, it does not show up in the select container. To fix this, you just need to do: `this.setState({selected_eml: event})`

Comment: I tried that, it displays the selected option now but it's not displaying the data returned by the selected option anymore. I don't get why that's happening....

Comment: What do you mean by "it's displaying the data anymore"? which data?

Comment: That was a typo, I edited my comment. The data I'm referring to is fetched upon selecting an option from the dropdown and is displayed in tabular format.

Comment: I think that is because in your componentDidUpdate you have passed the selected_eml which is an object now, as the email. You need to pass selected_eml.value to fix this.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve the code? Also I'd really appreciate if you could suggest me some material for learning react :)

Comment: The first point is that I think you don't have the componentDidUpdate for the purpose presented in this sample code. You just need to implement the required logic in the selectedUserHandler function. Another point is that I highly recommend writing functional components rather than class-based components. And, it is much better to have your api requests in a separate file and import them wherever you need to use them.